# Using external list to order a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
var results = (from bk in bookContext.Books
           orderby bk.id descending
           select bk).ToList();
```

The table "Book" also has a genre id and if a user subscribes into a specific genre, when listing suggested books I want to order by those subscribed genres first and then order by book id. I can get the list of subscribed genre ids as a list below.

```
List<int> subGenereIds = new List<int>() { 10, 12, 22 };
```

How can add the order by section to the initial Linq query above so that users get books that have genre id in list first and the rest after that?

Comment: You added the Entity Framework tag. Isn't `Book` related to `SubGenre` somehow? You would normally use `orderby bk.id descending, bk.SubGenre.Name`  or something

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto no I want to order by subscribed genres of a user, not by all genres. Once subscribed gneres are at the top, rest can be ordered only by book id. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get all subscribed genre of books and all the books at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to to the ordering in-memory since there's not a way to pass that ordering logic to SQL. You can do that by using `AsEnumerable()` to change the context from a SQL query to an in-memory query:

```
 var results = bookContext.Books
                          .AsEnumerable()
                          .OrderByDescending(bk => bk.Id)
                          .ThenBy(bk => subGenereIds.IndexOf(bk.Id));
```

Comment: order by subGenereIds should come first, then by id

Comment: @ManishM  not if the desired result is to be sorted by Id but then sorted by sub genre _within each Id group_.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it looks like you need to have as much of this as possible done in the the database.  Assuming that you have the books and the user subscriptions stored in the same place you can combine the query for the user's preferences with the search of the book table to get the result you're after.

For the sake of argument, let's assume you have some tables that look something like this as POCOs:

```
[Table("Books")]
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Genre { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public Date PublishDate { get; set; }
}

[Table("Genres")]
public class Genre
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserGenrePreferences")]
public class UserGenrePreference
{
    public int User { get; set; }
    public int Genre { get; set; }
}
```

For the sake of the example we have one genre per book and no duplicates in the `UserGenrePreferences` table.

The basic ordering might look something like this:

```
// get genre preferences for the selected user
var userPrefs =
    from pref in context.UserGenrePReferences
    where pref.User == userID
    select new { Genre = (int?)pref.Genre };

var result = 
    from book in context.Books
    join pref in userPrefs on book.Genre equals pref.Genre
    into prefTemp
    from pref in prefTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby (pref.Genre == null ? 1 : 0), book.ID
    select book;
```

This does an outer join against the user's genre preferences.  Books with a matching genre will have a non-null value in the matching `pref` record, so they will be placed before unmatched books in the result.  Pagination would then by handled by the normal `.Skip(...).Take(...)` method.

For very large data sets this will still take some time to run.  If you're expecting that the user will be paging through the data it might be a good idea to grab just the book IDs and cache those in memory.  Take the first few thousand results and look for more when needed for instance.  Then grab the book records when the user wants them, which will be much quicker than running the query above for every page.

---

If on the other hand your user preference data is not in the same database, you might be able to use the `Contains` method to do your ordering.

Assuming that you have an array of genre IDs in memory only you should be able to do this:

```
int[] userPrefs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5 };

var result = 
    from book in context.Books
    orderby (userPrefs.Contains(book.Genre) ? 0 : 1), book.ID
    select book;
```

Depending on the ORM this will translate into something similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Genre = 1 OR Genre = 2 OR Genre = 3 OR Genre = 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    ID
```

This can be fairly quick but if the list of preferences is very large it could be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that you write the more complex linq query to solve it.

Yes, it's becoming shorter that way but also becoming harder to read. The longer answer below. You can shorten it by yourself.

First you should get the ones which  have genreIds of subGenereIds list.

```
var onesWithGenreIdFromList = (from bk in bookContext.Books
where subGenereIds.Contains(bk.genreId).orderby bk.Id descending select bk).ToList();
```

Then get the rest of the list (ones don't have genreId of subGenereIds list) from your list.

```
var results = (from bk in bookContext.Books
where !subGenereIds.Contains(bk.genreId)
orderby bk.id descending
select bk).ToList();
```

As the last step you should add the first list to second one to create the order you would like:

```
onesWithGenreIdFromList.AddRange(results);
var lastResults = onesWithGenreIdFromList;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: @h-serhan-ekinci thanks for the answer. But this will not be efficient when you have millions of books and want to do pagination. Do you have any idea to make it work in one query so that pagination can be done without selecting all the items?